# Animating a 3d vector - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I am trying to animate a rotating 3d vector. everything more or less works, expect my update-funtion for the "FuncAnimation"-part of the code. When I run the code, I get the following error message:

```
"Error in line "the line with the code "vector.set_data(u[i], v[i], w[i])" ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
```

I have no idea what i am doing wrong, can anybody help?

```
from matplotlib import animation, rc
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
t_end = 20
u0 = [1 / np.sqrt(2)]
v0 = [1 / np.sqrt(2)]
w0 = [0]
y0 = u0 + v0 + w0
print(y0)
def ode45(t, y):
    u = np.array(y[0])
    v = np.array(y[1])
    w = np.array(y[2])
    omega = np.pi / 2
    delta = 0
    dudt = delta * v
    dvdt = -delta * u + omega * w
    dwdt = - omega * v
    return [dudt, dvdt, dwdt]

mysol = solve_ivp(ode45, [0, t_end], y0)
u = mysol.y[0]
v = mysol.y[1]
w = mysol.y[2]
r = np.mean(u ** 2 + v ** 2 + w ** 2)
print(r)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 101)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 101)
z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(theta)), np.cos(phi))
x = r * np.outer(np.cos(theta), np.sin(phi))
y = r * np.outer(np.sin(theta), np.sin(phi))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, alpha=0.2, color='gray')
vector, = ax.plot([], [], [])

def update(i):
    vector.set_data(u[i], v[i], w[i])
    return vector

ax.plot([0], [0], [0], 'ro')
ax.plot(u, v, w, color='blue')
steps = 100 * t_end
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t_end, interval=1, blit=True)
anim
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is creating a tuple:

```
vector, = ax.plot([], [], [])
```

Pyplot `.plot()` returns a list (typically of lines or markers) to plot or adjust. I don't think it returns a tuple. So, in

```
def update(i):
    vector.set_data(u[i], v[i], w[i])
    return vector
```

The `vector.set_data(u[i], v[i], w[i])` is calling `set_data` on a tuple of `(ax.plot.lines, None)`. I think this might be the problem.

**EDIT:**

You should be able to fix it with this:

```
vector = ax.plot([], [], [])
```

Comment: although fixing this problem, it now spits out :AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_data'
What does that mean?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. `lines` returned from `ax.plot()` is going to be a list of lines or markers. For future readers, this questions is answered. Please ask another one. You can tag me in it and I'll work on that.